# Mysql - выявить значения которые повторяются и сколько раз

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, как можна выявиться значения которые повторяются и показать сколько раз, ну и от наибольших повторений к наименьшим
Таблица называеться например table1  а ней строки:

*phoenix*@centrum.cz
_petr_riha@icloud.com
*money*@email.cz
*milena*@centrum.cz

Нужно выявить повторения после знака @, хочу понять каких имайлов больше всего используется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf4c0b/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`email` varchar(255))
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`email`)
VALUES
    ('foo@gmail.com'),
    ('bar@gmail.com'),
    ('root@mail.ru')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select count(1) cnt, SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1) as domain
from table1
group by domain having cnt>1
order by cnt desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf4c0b/5/0)**:

```
| cnt |    domain |
|-----|-----------|
|   2 | gmail.com |
```

Comment: На всякий случай, если нужны именно которые повторяются, а не встречают только один раз. Добавить к group by `having count(1) > 1`

Comment: @Sergey добавил

Comment: спасибо большое, все работает. @YuraIvanov